# Nagios-Agent Error Installation on OpenSuse

Tags: linux, nagios, opensuse

when I try to install the linux-nagios-agent on my linux server I get the error below:

```
/home/lost+found/linux-nrpe-agent # ./fullinstall
/etc/os-release: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Below is the content of the os-release

```
# cat /etc/os-release
NAME=openSUSE
VERSION = 12.1 (Asparagus)
VERSION_ID="12.1"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE 12.1 (Asparagus) (x86_64)"
ID=opensuse
```

Any idea what is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to double quote the `VERSION` string, here's how it looks in a newer version:

```
# cat /etc/os-release
NAME=openSUSE
VERSION="13.2 (Harlequin)"
VERSION_ID="13.2"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE 13.2 (Harlequin) (x86_64)"
ID=opensuse
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:opensuse:13.2"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.opensuse.org"
HOME_URL="https://opensuse.org/"
ID_LIKE="suse"
```